# SQL multiple natural inner joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, natural-join

Why does this correctly return the `Order ID` of an order, the `Customer ID` of the person who made the order, and the `Last Name` of the employee in charge of the transaction

```
SELECT "OrderID", "CustomerID", "LastName"
FROM orders O 
NATURAL INNER JOIN customers JOIN employees ON O."EmployeeID" = employees."EmployeeID";
```

while

```
SELECT "OrderID", "CustomerID", "LastName"
FROM orders O 
NATURAL INNER JOIN customers NATURAL INNER JOIN employees;
```

returns 0 rows?

I am sure that they have common columns.

`Table orders
OrderId
EmployeeID
CustomerID
...`

`Table employees
EmployeeID
...`

`Table customers
CustomerID
...`

Comment: What happens when you use a proper (i.e. explicit) join?

Comment: Unable to reproduce : see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ff9db/3 . It doesn't even seems to be case sensitive (but I may be wrong on this point).

Comment: At a guess, there are *too many* common columns, and one that's unexpected is matching. Don't use natural joins, they're terrible. Use `INNER JOIN ... ON (...)` or if you must, `INNER JOIN ... USING (colname)`.

Comment: @CraigRinger i followed your suggestion. But may i just ask why there would possibly be too many columns?

Comment: @user3903214 "NATURAL is a shorthand form of USING: it forms a USING list consisting of all column names that appear in both input tables. As with USING, these columns appear only once in the output table. If there are no common columns, NATURAL behaves like CROSS JOIN." [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

Comment: @nobodynoone im sorry but i still do not understand why the query failed to match the common fields. perhaps the natural joins were not executed in the "proper" order (e.g. left to right)?

Comment: @user3903214 one, to fully answer your question, would need actual table displays, constraints etc.

Comment: Edit your question. Paste in CREATE TABLE statements for each table. Also, what version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: If this is a production db, you probably have something like `last_updated` (timestamp) for auditing purposes.  A `NATURAL JOIN` will of course attempt include this column as part of the conditions, which is almost always going to fail.  That is, I think the same as @CraigRinger - too many identically named columns, that don't share the same data.  This is why I regard `USING`/`NATURAL JOIN` as mostly useless - most well-normalized sets tends to have only one or two joining keys per table (not many)... and production dbs have 4+ columns of auditing data.  Easier to list desired join keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your *full, unedited* schema it's hard to be sure, but I'd say there are more common columns than you intended.

E.g. as @ClockworkMuse sugested:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    OrderId integer primary key,
    EmployeeID integer not null,
    CustomerID integer not null,
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
    EmployeeID integer primary key,
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    ...
);
```

then `orders NATURAL JOIN employees` will be equivalent to `orders INNER JOIN employees USING (EmployeeID, created_at)`. Which surely isn't what you intended.

You should use `INNER JOIN ... USING (colname)` or `INNER JOIN ... ON (condition)`.

`NATURAL JOIN` is a poorly thought out feature that should really be avoided except on quick and dirty ad-hoc queries, if even then. Even if it works now, if you later add an unrelated column to a table it might change the meaning of existing queries. That's ... well, avoid natural joins.